# Time series: how much past predicts future

Tags: time-series, forecasting, finance, random-walk, forecastability

In financial (time series) statistics and forecasting we usually assume that the past of a series can predict the future to some extent. Every financial ad will warn you that investors should not assume that past performance (perfectly) predicts future performance, ie you can lose your money.

I am interested how we can quantify for a series **how much** the past does predict the future. The first idea is the use the inverse of the forecasting error. The smaller the error, the more past is relevant.

We know that some series follow a random walk and are very hard to predict. They have a unit root.

I am wondering whether there has been a rigorous derivation of a (past relevance) metric we can use here, that is independent of scale (we can compare between series) and maybe also indepedent of future and past (lookback) window choices.

Comment: We use forecasting error estimates to do this, but there's a big assumption of "ceteris paribus" -- i.e. that the past conditions will be roughly equal to the future conditions.  Consider, for example, forecasting hospital bed usage using data up to 2019.  The conditions since the start of the pandemic mean those forecasts wouldn't be very good.